# How lock the unlock screen after wrong password attempts?

Tags: password, lock-screen, pam, xscreensaver

I enabled pam_tally2 to lock a user after several password attempts. It works well at the TTY, login screen and ssh.

However, I usually lock the screen when leaving the computer. You can type as many wrong passwords as you want at the unlocking screen, while the account won't be locked like pam_tally2.

Is there any way to lock the user after several wrong attempts when unlocking the screen?

Comment: Was able to reproduce by configuring pam_tally2 inside common-auth and Mate's lock screen. mate-screensaver properly includes common-auth. Good luck.